# Error with SPPID's Interop.Llama library : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80000008): No DBConnect for Data_Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, com-interop

I'm having the following error usiing SmartPlant P&ID (SPPID) automation library Llama (Interop.Llama.dll):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80000008): No DBConnect for Data_Dictionary
at Llama._LMEquipments.Collect(LMADataSource& DataSource, _LMAItem& Parent, String& RelationshipName, LMAFilter& Filter)
```

Here is the code that calls it:

```
Dim objDS As Llama.LMADataSource
Dim objEquips As Llama.LMEquipments        

objDS = New Llama.LMADataSource
objDS.ProjectNumber = Project.SPPIDName & "!" & Project.SPPIDName
objDS.SiteNode = Project.SiteServer

objEquips = New Llama.LMEquipments
objEquips.Collect(objDS) ' throws Exception
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

SPPID is an engineering tool used to develop and manage piping and instrumentation diagrams. Llama is an [automation library](http://www.intergraph.com/global/ca/assets/local/SPPIDAutomation1V2007.pdf) supplied with SPPID.

Answer (score 2):

This means that your code can't find that specific project in SPPID available plant structures database. Beware that the **ProjectNumber** string is **case sensitive** .

In my case, all I had to do was to change project name, from PF2_REF to PF2_Ref (replaced last two letters for lowercase equivalents).